# Finding the longest text fragment that exists in both strings

Tags: c#

I need to find the longest text fragment that exists in both strings and number of the line in which the fragment starts for both strings. In this case I'm storing the text in `Book` class, because it makes sense for other things I have to do with it. I need a method inside my main class, which would look something like this:

```
static void FindLongestFragment(Book book1, Book book2, out string fragment, out int lineNumber1, out int lineNumber2)
```

However, I can't think of an algorithm to do this. Here is what my program looks so far:

```
class Book
{
    static char[] Separators = new char[] { ' ', '.', ',', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t', '\n', '\'', '"', '"' };

    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public LineContainer Lines { get; private set; }

    public string[] Words { get { return Text.Split(Separators); } }

    public Book(string[] lines)
    {
        Text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Text += lines[i] + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        Lines = new LineContainer(lines);
    }


class LineContainer
{
    private List<Line> Lines;
    public int Count { get { return Lines.Count; } }

    public LineContainer(string[] lines)
    {
        Lines = new List<Line>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            Lines.Add(new Line(lines[i], i));
        }
    }

    public Line Get(int index)
    {
        return Lines[index];
    }
}

class Line
{
    static char[] Separators = new char[] { ' ', '.', ',', '!', ':', ';', '(', ')', '\t', '\n', '\'', '"', '"' };

    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public int Length { get { return Text.Length; } }
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public string[] Words { get { return Text.Split(Separators); } }

    public Line(string text, int number)
    {
        Text = text;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like homework... You should post your expected input and output as  "longest text fragment" is too ambiguous.

Comment: [Longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)? There is even pseudo-code you just need to implement...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yes, that's the thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are some ideas...

You might start by creating 2 `SortedSet` with the words from each file. That way, you can determine which words are only in one file. That way, you would have every sequence of that contains words that are in the other string.

After that, you might want to build a dictionary that would contains all possible start indexes for a give word : `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.

Then for each starting word of the first string, you might want to find the best possible match. You would remember the best match found. That way, you can eliminate any sequence that are too short to be the best one at that point.

For that purpose, it might be interesting to have a dictionary that would give the maximum length from a starting word. That way, you can easily eliminate many sequences particularly.

Another trick that might help filtering would be to build information on consecutive pairs. That way, it would also be possible to cut sequence at any point where a pair of words exist only in one phrase.

So if you do those steps in a loop or recursively, you would rapidly eliminate a lot of cases...